A schema for awallet system that allows transfers between users
I am currently working on a wallet system that allows transfers of money between users. I tried creating this as a Stack Overflow question, but it was rejected.  I'm not sure if this is the right place, but certainly looks like it.
I came up with the following structure, intending for the system to be robust, scalable, and capable of handling various types of financial transactions with proper tracking and integrity.
I am using PostgreSQL 16, and this is my schema:
CREATE TABLE users (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE wallets (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    user_id UUID REFERENCES users(id),
    balance NUMERIC(15, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    transaction_type VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (transaction_type IN ('credit', 'debit', 'transfer', 'refund', 'void')),
    amount NUMERIC(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded')),
    reference_id UUID REFERENCES transactions(id),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE transfers (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    sender_wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    receiver_wallet_id UUID REFERENCES wallets(id),
    transaction_id UUID REFERENCES transactions(id),
    amount NUMERIC(15, 2) NOT NULL,
    currency VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded')),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

In order to know the balance of a wallet, my application can do the following query:
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'credit' THEN amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'debit' THEN -amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'transfer' AND wallet_id = '$walletid' THEN -amount 
            WHEN transaction_type = 'transfer' AND wallet_id != '$walletid' THEN amount 
            ELSE 0 
        END
    ), 0) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE wallet_id = '$walletid' AND status = 'completed';

There are some caveats though:

I heard that money should be stored as bigint in cents, instead of a float. Is this still the case?
As wallets grow older, how to speed up the balance query?
How should external transactions be designed in this system? Meaning: the custom funds his wallet via PayPal or Stripe. Does that money come from an "Internal" or "System" wallet?


redundant wallets
CREATE TABLE wallets (
    id        UUID  PRIMARY KEY ...,
    user_id   UUID  REFERENCES users(id), ...
    currency  VARCHAR(3) ...

This isn't bad.
It would be better if it enforced some uniqueness.
My concern is that a given user could have a pair of USD wallets
and three CHF wallets, leading to regrettable confusion.
Consider using a compound
PK
of (user_id, currency).
The FK
relationship is very nice and should remain.
floating point
    balance NUMERIC(15, 2) DEFAULT 0.00,


I heard that money should be stored as bigint in cents, instead of a float. Is this still the case?

Yes.
Your balance column is very nice.
It stores an integer number of cents.
The trouble is that
FP
stores some values as repeating decimals.
If I have a dollar and I promise to give one-third to Alice
and two-thirds to Bob, it's clear that the repeating
decimal 0.33333333... will lead to roundoff trouble,
and probably I will just give Alice three dimes and three pennies.
That's what happens when decimal notation collides with that odd divisor.
Something similar happens with binary notation.
Suppose I had twenty cents and you gave me a dime.
Let's ask python's FP system how much I have at the end.
>>> .2 + .1
0.30000000000000004

Ooohhhh, bad luck. Neither one of those fractions (2/10 & 1/10)
are exactly representable as a binary fraction.
This stems from ten having an odd factor: five.
Well, no matter, let's fix it by giving that dime back to you.
How much do I have now?
>>> .2 + .1 - .1
0.20000000000000004

Right. Well, we don't want finance systems exhibiting such behavior.
Which is why using scaled integers in your schema,
such as integer number of pennies, makes so much sense.
enum
Validating status here is lovely.
    status VARCHAR NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded')),

But it shows up multiple times.
Consider giving a name to that list.
CREATE TYPE valid_status AS ENUM ('pending', 'completed', 'voided', 'refunded');

account history
WHERE wallet_id = '$walletid' AND status = 'completed';


As wallets grow older, how to speed up the balance query?

The query plan is going to exploit the PK,
so that much is pretty nice.
You could additionally offer a compound
index of (wallet_id, status)
so there's no need to retrieve pending or refunded rows,
but that would offer only a minor win.
account snapshots
After a wallet accumulates K completed transactions
(maybe K = 1000),
siphon off all its funds into a newly created wallet
with a new wallet_id GUID.
A pair of freshly INSERTed transaction rows will log the transfer.
Now the history information is available for the old wallet,
but what we care about is querying the new one,
and that always returns a bounded number of rows.
Alternatively, tack on a current_balance column which
caches the sum-to-date. Of course this is
denormed
data. If somehow it doesn't match the history, which should we believe?
external APIs

How should external [PayPal or Stripe] transactions be designed in this system?

That's outside the scope of this question,
as you did not submit any code that interacts with such an API.
Ask on SO, or propose a code review here of some newly authored
code which does implement such interactions.

A curiosity where you talk about how is bad to use floating point number for currency: if I am not wrong, NUMERIC is not floating point, so isn't it OK?

Yeah, I have that question to. Is the Money class of Martin Fowler still relevant in databases of today?

@MatteoTassinari, the OP code uses a scaled integer, which is perfect. The “,2” says we’re scaling by 10^2, we’re scaling by 100. Some programming languages use a Decimal() class for this concept. Sure, you could name it Money(). The important point is to manipulate integer quantities on the inside, rather than infinite repeating binary fractions. And then for external output we can put the decimal point back in so it displays nicely.

Time zone
Instead of using naive datetimes, I would strongly recommend time zone-aware types eg TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. See relevant doc for available options. A datetime value without context is ambiguous, so you can't really tell without checking the server configuration.
In a distributed architecture, it is plausible that you would have geographically distributed servers running on different time zones. Then you are missing context. Sometimes you will have to debug code and need to correlate user activity with logs or other data. It is frustrating to be comparing apples to oranges.
If you change hosting plans, the TZ could change overnight as well. After all, the mainland US alone has at least 4 time zones. But your DB will not be consistent, because the baseline is not the same for the whole lifetime of your data.
If you can't tell a user exactly when (in their own time zone or yours) a transaction took place, you have a problem.
Also, this information may be crucial to determine the applicable exchange rate or even compound interest.
KYC
I suspect your activity may be regulated, subject to KYC and various compliance rules. Then I'd expect the users table to grow quite a bit. This is the bare minimum for a PoC. There is no field for a hashed password, nor is 2FA present it seems. Plus, you will probably need to log certain events like login/logout and any sensitive activity like changes to the user profile.
All of that is not really important for the code review, but it has to be considered in the development roadmap. Traceability is especially important in applications that deal with money.
Balance
If I am thinking about the user frontend, there could be a dashboard of some sort, where I'd see an overview of my balances in different currencies. You probably don't want to compute the amounts on the fly, based on transaction history. That might be a use case for aggregate tables.
UUID
Is this to prevent enumeration attacks?
transactions vs transfers
I don't exactly understand how the two tables relate to each other, but at first glance there seems to be some overlap between the two.
Decimals
The doc confirms that NUMERIC is a proper choice for storing monetary amounts. But it is a slower data type. Other DBMS (eg SQL Server) also have dedicated data types for monetary amounts, so this is where reading the doc becomes essential to determine the optimum choice.
NUMERIC(15, 2) provides for a scale of two, that is two decimals. But some currencies use more eg KWD (Kuwaiti Dinar) has 3 decimals. The Bahraini dinar as well.
In business environments, I have seen tables with room for 4 decimals in currency fields.  The guy at the logistics told me that some suppliers quote unit prices with 4 decimals, even though there would be rounding up of the grand total. But on large orders every fraction of a penny counts.
If you will be dealing with cryptocurrencies maybe you'll need even more.
Not so UNIQUE constraint
Afaik the UNIQUE constraint is case sensitive, so if a user is registered in your database with E-mail info@example.com, I could still register with INFO@EXAMPLE.COM with no problem. This is not what you want.

The first approach is to simply normalize this value to lowercase in your application, but your DB has to rely on the upstream code for data quality.
The second approach (I prefer) would be simply an index: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_unique_idx on users (LOWER(email)); (untested)
Third option: you could use the citext (case insensitive text) type as described here.


Yes, UUID was chosen to prevent enumeration attack. Is it a bad choice? Should I stick to integer internally, and have an external_id UUID?

Transactions are there to log credits and debits in the wallets themselves. The transfers tell me the from and the to. So, if A sends 10 to B, that results in 3 rows: one debit of 10 in A, one credit of 10 in B, and one transfer log with the ID of A, ID of B, who is the from, who is the to, the amount, date, notes, etc.

@vinnylinux I don't think this is bad, it's good that you thought about enumeration as long as it's not just security by obscurity . Other mechanisms such as rate limiting can be leveraged too. For example to thottle scrapers.

@vinnylinux, sometimes locality of reference matters. It would be common for Alice to do a bunch of transactions in one wallet within a short span of time, and then an hour later Bob might do another bunch of transactions in another wallet. For operations like summing to find wallet's current balance, it will be desirable for all those Alice transactions to appear on one or a handful of disk blocks, and similarly for Bob. Less I/O, better cache hit ratios. Timestamps or serial ids promote locality, but random UUIDs don't.
